kafka broker immediately shuts down upon starting
We are running a kafka cluster of 6 brokers. 5 of the brokers seem to be totally fine, but when we turn on the 6th one it causes lag and we see the below in the logs. Any assistance into what could be causing this would be appreciated. We are running kafka version 3.5.1 with scala version of 2.12 and zookeeper version 3.8.2
[2024-08-20 08:20:07,242] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 4] Removed fetcher for partitions Set(jeno-0, jeno_jeno-http-0) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2024-08-20 08:20:07,255] INFO [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1]: Shutting down (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2024-08-20 08:20:07,256] INFO [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1]: Stopped (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
[2024-08-20 08:20:07,256] INFO [ReplicaFetcherThread-0-1]: Shutdown completed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)

We've tried restarting all of the zookeeper nodes and kafka nodes. Then started the zookeepers. Then started the kafka nodes 1 by 1, but the result was the same. Was reading that maybe the kafka logs dir was filled with space but that is not the issue here as we have a /var/kafka directory mounted that is only at 1% capacity at this time.
Also here are the details for the topic:
Topic: jeno
TopicId: zUBXkX0AQgijNqN0L-KuWg 
PartitionCount: 2   
ReplicationFactor: 3    
Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824,max.message.bytes=10485880
Topic: jeno Partition: 0    Leader: 4   Replicas: 4,1,2 Isr: 1,2,4
Topic: jeno Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1,2,3


In the logs we were seeing some issues with broker ids. We were able to resolve by uninstalling zookeeper and kafka from the cluster and reinstalling it.
